# How to change the default admin username and admin password in RockMongo?

Tags: mongodb

I am using RockMongo admin tool and I can access it usingthe default username admin and admin password settings. I would like to change it however the documentation is a little cryptic. I have even emailed the author but no response.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file called **config.php** in your RockMongo folder, you can set the username/password in there.

Depending on your RockMongo version the line will look something like this ...

[image]